# Jenkins multiple access control mechanism

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using access control on Jenkins with openid plugin. Users are authenticated through Google account.

But i also need to have users created on Jenkins internally. i.e role based access control.

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to make it possible to use multiple access control mechanisms at the same time ? Currently i can only select one.

Any plugins to make it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, your users need a google apps account to login.

But that shouldn't be a problem with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

Comment: Well, it is problem because what i really want to do is to integrate Jenkins with Redmine through Redmine's Hudson plugin. Unfortunately Redmine's Hudson plugin can not get logged in to Jenkins through openid. That's why i needed a used on Jenkin's own user database to connect Redmine to Jenkins

Comment: Yea, you'll probably only be able to integrate it from jenkins' side.https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Redmine+Plugin